# unable to implement remove class & add-class feature of jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have this below script

```
  $.fn.SoundToggle = function() {
            var sound_staus = $('#soundstatus').data('status');
            if (sound_staus === 'mute')
            {
                $('#soundstatus').data('status', 'unmute');//ui-icon ui-icon-volume-off
                $("#soundstatus span").removeClass("ui-icon ui-icon-volume-off").addClass("ui-icon ui-icon-volume-on");
            } else
            {
                $('#soundstatus').data('status', 'mute');
                $("#soundstatus span").removeClass("ui-icon ui-icon-volume-on").addClass("ui-icon ui-icon-volume-off");
            }
        }
```

And html

```
<a class="button"  title="Sound Mute/Unmute" data-status="mute" onClick="$(this).SoundToggle();" id="soundstatus"> 
                    <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-volume-on"></span>
</a>
```

I want to toggle jquery ui `Speaker Mute & unmute` two icons on click.

But my above code is not showing output properly, instead of removing previous its showing two icons at once like this image:

[image]

Please help me why my code is not working fine.

Comment: @Rani...you will Don't worry? Did you try `toggleClass`http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/ or .addClass and .removeClass in seperate lines

Comment: bacause it's 3 min ago .. wait for few more .

Comment: Why are you removing and adding the same class `ui-icon`?

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle.com demonstrating the problem? BTW, your function should use `$(this)` rather than hard-coding `#soundstatus`.

Comment: @Barmar or better yet, `this`

Comment: @rani That explains why you remove and add `ui-icon-volume-on` and `ui-icon-volume-off`. But why are you removing `ui-icon` and then adding it back?

Comment: @rani what he's saying is there's no point in removing/adding ui-icon because it's needed for both versions of it.

Comment: Because in your example, your initial value of status is UNMUTE

Comment: Although when I change his fiddle to use `data-status="mute"` like the question, I still don't see the multiple-icon symptom he describes.

Comment: Since it doesn't occur in the fiddle, can you give us a link to the application?

Comment: There must be something you're not showing that's causing this. If you're getting multiple icons, there must be more than one icon span. I even tried giving both classes to the same span, it didn't result in overlapping icons like that.

Comment: @Barmar You are right, because of lengthy code, it was confilicting with other `span` now i got the correct output.  I answered it here  http://stackoverflow.com/a/19256516/2732367

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Jhonatas Kleinkauff said: you have your `status` and icons mixed in your initial code. On the first click, the status would be `mute`, so you would try to remove the class `ui-icon-volume-off`, which is not there, so in fact, no class gets removed. Afterwards you are adding `ui-icon-volume-on` and end up having both classes set at the same time, so both icons are shown.

You are doing it right in your fiddle though (status is `unmute`, so sound is on and the class should be `ui-icon-volume-on`, which it is).

To fix the code in your question, you would have to either switch the initial status to `unmute` as you did in the fiddle:

```
<a class="button" title="Sound Mute/Unmute" data-status="unmute" onClick="$(this).SoundToggle();" id="soundstatus"> 
    <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-volume-on"></span>
</a>
```

or set the other HTML class:

```
<a class="button" title="Sound Mute/Unmute" data-status="mute" onClick="$(this).SoundToggle();" id="soundstatus"> 
    <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-volume-off"></span>
</a>
```

You might want to look into jQuery [`.toggleClass`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) function which has a nice second parameter, a boolean switch to indicate if you want to add or remove the class. You could then do something like this:

```
var $soundIcon = $('#soundstatus span');
var soundShouldBeTurnedOn = currentStatus === "mute";
$soundIcon.toggleClass("ui-icon-volume-on", soundShouldBeTurnedOn)
          .toggleClass("ui-icon-volume-off", !soundShouldBeTurnedOn);
```

Comment: But it is working in your fiddle, just get the code from there. The way I understand it: if the `data-status` is `mute`, the icon should be `off`. This is different in your HTML but correct in your JS.

Comment: yeah , you are right. I tested my fiddle also. But its again displaying three icons . I am getting mad

Answer (score 1):

```
 $.fn.SoundToggle = function() {
            var sound_staus = $('#soundstatus').data('status');
            if (sound_staus === 'mute')
            {
                $('#soundstatus').data('status', 'unmute');//ui-icon ui-icon-volume-off
                $("#soundstatus span").removeClass("ui-icon ui-icon-volume-on").addClass("ui-icon ui-icon-volume-off");
            } else
            {
                $('#soundstatus').data('status', 'mute');
                $("#soundstatus span").removeClass("ui-icon ui-icon-volume-off").addClass("ui-icon ui-icon-volume-on");
            }
        }
```

On the original code:

```
 if (sound_staus === 'mute')
            {
                ...
                $("#soundstatus span").removeClass("ui-icon ui-icon-volume-off").addClass("ui-icon ui-icon-volume-on");
            }..
```

But, the initial value of status IS MUTE AND the class is ui-icon ui-icon-volume-on

So, why when mute, you try to remove ui-icon ui-icon-volume-off instead on?

Comment: i'm having a hard time figuring out what you've changed.

Comment: He swapped `on` and `off`.

Comment: Your answer is displaying just opposite icon of my wish.Which is wrong. Just now i tested my above question code. Here is the fiddle of my above question http://jsfiddle.net/TrxHx/4/ . Its working fine, but why its not working fine in my app?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by providing `id` to the icon div.

I think because of the huge code, it was showing multiple icons, by confilcting with several span.

I thought, id should be unique hence i added a id attribute i.e `id="volumeicondId"`

```
<a id="soundstatus" class="button"  title="Sound Mute/Unmute" data-status="unmute" onClick="$(this).SoundToggle();" > 
                    <span id="volumeicondId" class="ui-icon ui-icon-volume-on"></span>
```

And js function

```
  $.fn.SoundToggle = function() {
            var sound_staus = $('#soundstatus').data('status');
            if (sound_staus === 'unmute')
            {
                $('#soundstatus').data('status', 'mute');//ui-icon ui-icon-volume-off
                $("#volumeicondId").removeClass("ui-icon ui-icon-volume-on").addClass("ui-icon ui-icon-volume-off");
            } else
            {
                $('#soundstatus').data('status', 'unmute');
                $("#volumeicondId").removeClass("ui-icon ui-icon-volume-off").addClass("ui-icon ui-icon-volume-on");
            }
        }
```